# reading member values from java objects serialized to disc without the classes

Tags: java, parsing, serialization

is it possible to read member values from java objects that were serialized to disc without the classes of the objects?

i think this is a big NO, ITS NOT POSSIBLE -- but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "without the classes of the objects?" Do you mean "without the metadata the defines what class it is?"

Comment: I think he means, if he doesnt have the definition of the class to fit the data back into. And the answer is NO. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible - you just have to reimplement anything that ObjectInputStream does, skipping the parts you don't want.

The **Java Object Serialization Specification** contains a chapter [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), which contains everything you need to know.

So, if your question is **Can I be sure that nobody can access the content of my objects without deserializing the whole objects**, the answer is **No**. See also the appendix A  [Security in Object Serialization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/security.html), which elaborates this a bit.